# How can I find my recent votes cast?

Tags: discussion, support, votes

If I voted 30 times in a day and forgot to which questions/answers I have voted.

**How can I find my recent votes cast?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Unfortunately, you can't. There is nothing in the interface that lists the posts you voted on, just the total vote counts per week, month and all time.</strike>

See [Can I see my vote history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/can-i-see-my-vote-history) on the main meta.

---

The above now obsolete information: 
As of 2012-04-26, there is now a *Votes* tab in your user profile ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/where-did-the-votes-tab-go/130380#130380)).

You'll find your voting activity there, along with close/reopen and delete/undelete vote history. This is only visible to yourself, others don't see that information in your profile.